# SVG animation guidance needed

Tags: animation, svg, svg-animate

I read this Pocket Guide to SVG today and learned a lot from it, but... it does not cover animation. I need some guidance on how to do a simple animation. I dont need any transitions between frames, I just want to define shapes for frame one, shapes for frame two, etc.

https://svgpocketguide.com/book/

```
<!-- https://svgpocketguide.com/book/#section-4 -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="1080" height="1080">
    <!-- the doctype and svg need to be like this to render in Firefox -->
    <rect width="1080" height="1080" fill="white"/>

<!-- delay frames by waiting 0.5 seconds between frames -->

    <animation frame 1>
        <line x1="75" y1="75" x2="10" y2="50" stroke="hsl(0,82%,56%)" stroke-width="3"/>
        <line x1="75" y1="75" x2="175" y2="475" stroke="hsl(236,82%,56%)" stroke-width="3"/>
        <circle cx="10" cy="50" r="5" fill="black" />
        <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="5" fill="black" />
        <circle cx="175" cy="475" r="5" fill="black" />
    </animation frame 1>

    <animation frame 2>
        <line x1="75" y1="75" x2="10" y2="50" stroke="hsl(0,82%,56%)" stroke-width="3"/>
        <line x1="75" y1="75" x2="175" y2="475" stroke="hsl(236,82%,56%)" stroke-width="3"/>
        <circle cx="10" cy="50" r="5" fill="black" />
        <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="5" fill="black" />
        <circle cx="175" cy="475" r="5" fill="black" />
    </animation frame 2>

</svg>
```

Comment: That's not really how [SMIL works](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SMIL_animations)

Comment: Well I found this. The keyword is "keyframes" but it shows transformations applied to shapes. Not switching between shapes.

Comment: This is the closest things to keyframes that I found yet: https://oak.is/thinking/animated-svgs/

Comment: Discrete calcMode is what I need, what I meant as "keyframes". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/calcMode

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- https://svgpocketguide.com/book/#section-4 -->
<!-- https://oak.is/thinking/animated-svgs/ -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="1080" height="1080">
    <rect width="1080" height="1080" fill="white"/>

    <line x1="400" y1="400" x2="10" y2="515" stroke="hsl(250,82%,56%)" stroke-width="3">
        <animate
            attributeName="x1"
            dur="0.5s"
            values="50;100;200;350;400"
            calcMode="discrete"
            repeatCount="1"
        />
        <animate
            attributeName="y1"
            dur="0.5s"
            values="50;100;200;350;400"
            calcMode="discrete"
            repeatCount="1"
        />
        <animate
            attributeName="stroke"
            dur="0.5s"
            values="hsl(50,82%,56%);hsl(100,82%,56%);hsl(150,82%,56%);hsl(200,82%,56%);hsl(250,82%,56%)"
            calcMode="discrete"
            repeatCount="1"
        />
    </line>

    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="5" fill="black" />
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="5" fill="black" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="5" fill="black" />
    <circle cx="350" cy="350" r="5" fill="black" />
    <circle cx="400" cy="400" r="5" fill="black" />

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question shows a method for frame-based animation in an SVG.  It uses CSS animation, but you could achieve the same thing with SMIL.  However, the CSS way is a little cleaner IMO.

[SIMPLE – Animate Multiple SVGs in Sequence (like a looping GIF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893587/simple-animate-multiple-svgs-in-sequence-like-a-looping-gif)

Here's another answer, that may help: [SVG frame-based animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316354/svg-frame-based-animation)